# Summatory function of Moebius and Euler's totient function over $y$-smooth numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $y \geq 1$. We say that a positive integer $n$ is $y$*-smooth* if $n$ has no prime factors larger than $y$. Let $x \geq y$. Let $\mu$ and $\varphi$ be the Moebius and Euler's totient function respectively. What are good upper bounds for the absolute value of the sum
$$
S(x,y) = \sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ n \text{ is } y-\text{smooth}}}\mu(n)?
$$
For the following sum, can we give a good lower bound?
$$
T(x,y) = \sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ n \text{ is } y-\text{smooth}}}\varphi(n)
$$

Comment: It depends on how large is $x$. For $x \ge \prod_{p \le y}p$ then $S(x,y)=0$. What do you need the bound for ? $\zeta(s)\prod_{p \le y} (1-p^{-s})$ is useful to count the number of zeros in $[1,2,\sigma] \times i[0,T]$ so you can search in the corresponding papers.

Comment: @reuns: What is the notation $[1,2,\sigma]$? Maybe you mean $[1/2,\sigma]$, but I'm not sure?